# How do I pass a variable from .js page into a .aspx page and have it available to me in an .aspx.js page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP and I am trying to pass a variable into a .aspx.js page so I can use it in an if statement to determine whether or not something should be displayed.

I have a .js page that calls a method which I have added a variable to:

```
if(strStatus == 4 || strStatus == 7) {
        LMS_Roster_WaivedNotes(strStatus);
    }
```

The method called is as follows which I have added the parameter for status

```
function LMS_Roster_WaivedNotes(strStatus) {
var strWindowName = "WaivedNotes";
var strRetVal     = null ;
var iLaunchWidth  = 400 ;
var iLaunchHeight = 200 ;

var objForm = document.forms["frmActRoster"];

var strPath = _UTL_GetPagePath("management/LMS_ActRosterWaived.aspx?Status=" + strStatus);
```

I have added the strStatus param to the end of my URL which calls the .aspx page.

At this point this is where I'm confused.

What do I add to my .aspx page to store this value?

From the .aspx page it calls a method:

```
LMS_WaivedNotes_Show_UI();
```

This calls into the .aspx.js page which renders the HTML.

```
function LMS_WaivedNotes_Show_UI()
{
pc.Logger.DebugFunctionEntry("LMS_WaivedNotes_Show_UI");

var objHtml               = null;
var objHtmlTable;
etc......
```

From this page I need to have the strStatus available to me in order to use it in an if statment.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ASPX HiddenField control. In your ASPX code-behind Page_Load method, get the querystring parameter and set the HiddenField value.

```
protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var querystring = this.Request.QueryString["strStatus"];
    this.MyHiddenField.Value = querystring;

}
```

You can then access this strStatus value in javascript:

```
var strStatus = document.getElementById('<%= MyHiddenField.ClientID %>');
```

However, if you only require this strStatus value for use in JavaScript, it would be more efficient to just get the query string value directly using JavaScript.

https://davidwalsh.name/query-string-javascript

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if I don't have a C# code behind page, only a .aspx page?

Comment: Is it possible to access a field via jquery in a .aspx.js page? I'm trying something like this.   var waivedStatus = $('#idfrmActRoster input[name=Status]').val();

Comment: If you want to access the value of an element a form input element using jQuery, you can just use $('#my-input-element-id').val() where my-input-element-id is the id you have associated with the input element

Comment: You must be using in-line code. Then the Page_Load method will need to be written inside a script tag.... <script runat="server">protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { ..... } </script> For separation of server side and client side code, I would recommend using a code-behind file instead of writing in-line code. Will make your code much easier to maintain rather than in one large file.